# CustomTkinter invalid command name

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, error-handling, customtkinter

Every time I close (destroy) a window in customtkinter and open a new customtkinter window by importing it, I receive an error like this in the terminal:

```
invalid command name "2464108484160update"
    while executing
"2464108484160update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2464127417408check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"2464127417408check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
```

This error pops up in the terminal but still displays the new window. I can cycle in between both of these windows a few times before the window automatically closes on its own.

The code I wrote:

```
def SignUp(self):
    Win.destroy()
    import SignUp_Page

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Window

Win = CTk(fg_color="#D6D6EA")

#Window Settings:

Win.geometry("900x500")
Win.resizable(width= False, height= False)
Win.title("Login Page")
Background = CTkImage(Image.open("Graphics\Front_Page_Login.png"), size=(900, 500))
Show_Background = CTkLabel(Win, image = Background, text= None)
Show_Background.place(x= 0, y=0)

# Frame:

LogFrame = CTkFrame(Win, border_width = 0, fg_color="transparent")
LogFrame.place(relx = 0.78, rely = 0.51, anchor = "center")

# Login Widgets

Lbl_L = CTkLabel(Win,text= "Login", font = ("Arial", 23, UNDERLINE))
Lbl_Usn_L = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Username", font = ("Arial", 13))
Lbl_PassW_L = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Password", font = ("Arial", 13))
Lbl_SignUp_Show = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text = "Need an account?", font = ("Arial", 13, "bold", UNDERLINE))
Lbl_Reset = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Reset password?", font = ("Arial", 13, "bold", UNDERLINE))
Ent_Log_Usn = CTkEntry (LogFrame, corner_radius= 20)
Ent_Log_PassW = CTkEntry (LogFrame, show="*", corner_radius= 20)
Check_Log_PassW_Var = IntVar()
Check_Log_PassW = CTkCheckBox(LogFrame, text= "Show password", variable= Check_Log_PassW_Var, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, checkbox_width= 18, checkbox_height= 18, command= Log_Toggle)
Check_Remb_Var = IntVar()
Check_Remb = CTkCheckBox(LogFrame, text= "Remember me", variable= Check_Remb_Var, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, checkbox_width= 18, checkbox_height= 18)
Bt_Log = CTkButton(LogFrame, text="Login", corner_radius= 20, hover_color= "#0e02e3", command= Login)

Lbl_L.place(x= 691, y= 10)
Lbl_Usn_L.grid(column= 0, row= 1, padx = 5)
Lbl_PassW_L.grid(column= 0, row= 2, padx = 5)
Lbl_SignUp_Show.grid(column= 0, row= 5)
Lbl_SignUp_Show.bind("<Button-1>", command= SignUp)
Lbl_Reset.grid(column= 1, row= 5)
Lbl_Reset.bind("<Button-1>", command= Reset_PassW)
Ent_Log_Usn.grid(column= 1 , row= 1, padx= 5, pady = 5)
Ent_Log_PassW.grid(column= 1 , row= 2, padx= 5)
Check_Log_PassW.grid(column= 0, row= 3, padx = 7, pady = 2)
Check_Remb.grid(column = 0, row = 4, padx = 15)
Bt_Log.place(x = 141, y = 78)

Win.mainloop()
```

I've tried to use try except in it and it didn't seem to remove this error in the terminal. Also tried to use winfo_children to destroy all of the widgets before importing the new window and the same issue still occurred.

Any way to fix this?

Used try except statements and winfo_children to destroy all prior widgets before destroying the main window and the error still occurred. Was expecting that the new window would pop up with no error in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**Description:**
So the issue is that you are performing an action inside the mainloop of you `Win` window after using the `Win.destroy()` function causing some mishandling in the back. I was stuck in a similar situation like yours but got out using `.withdraw()` function first then `.quit()` function.

**Solution:**

Try this modified code of yours, hope it helps!

```
def SignUp(self):
    Win.withdraw()
    Win.quit()
    import SignUp_Page

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Window

Win = CTk(fg_color="#D6D6EA")

#Window Settings:

Win.geometry("900x500")
Win.resizable(width= False, height= False)
Win.title("Login Page")
Background = CTkImage(Image.open("Graphics\Front_Page_Login.png"), size=(900, 500))
Show_Background = CTkLabel(Win, image = Background, text= None)
Show_Background.place(x= 0, y=0)

# Frame:

LogFrame = CTkFrame(Win, border_width = 0, fg_color="transparent")
LogFrame.place(relx = 0.78, rely = 0.51, anchor = "center")

# Login Widgets

Lbl_L = CTkLabel(Win,text= "Login", font = ("Arial", 23, UNDERLINE))
Lbl_Usn_L = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Username", font = ("Arial", 13))
Lbl_PassW_L = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Password", font = ("Arial", 13))
Lbl_SignUp_Show = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text = "Need an account?", font = ("Arial", 13, "bold", UNDERLINE))
Lbl_Reset = CTkLabel(LogFrame, text= "Reset password?", font = ("Arial", 13, "bold", UNDERLINE))
Ent_Log_Usn = CTkEntry (LogFrame, corner_radius= 20)
Ent_Log_PassW = CTkEntry (LogFrame, show="*", corner_radius= 20)
Check_Log_PassW_Var = IntVar()
Check_Log_PassW = CTkCheckBox(LogFrame, text= "Show password", variable= Check_Log_PassW_Var, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, checkbox_width= 18, checkbox_height= 18, command= Log_Toggle)
Check_Remb_Var = IntVar()
Check_Remb = CTkCheckBox(LogFrame, text= "Remember me", variable= Check_Remb_Var, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, checkbox_width= 18, checkbox_height= 18)
Bt_Log = CTkButton(LogFrame, text="Login", corner_radius= 20, hover_color= "#0e02e3", command= Login)

Lbl_L.place(x= 691, y= 10)
Lbl_Usn_L.grid(column= 0, row= 1, padx = 5)
Lbl_PassW_L.grid(column= 0, row= 2, padx = 5)
Lbl_SignUp_Show.grid(column= 0, row= 5)
Lbl_SignUp_Show.bind("<Button-1>", command= SignUp)
Lbl_Reset.grid(column= 1, row= 5)
Lbl_Reset.bind("<Button-1>", command= Reset_PassW)
Ent_Log_Usn.grid(column= 1 , row= 1, padx= 5, pady = 5)
Ent_Log_PassW.grid(column= 1 , row= 2, padx= 5)
Check_Log_PassW.grid(column= 0, row= 3, padx = 7, pady = 2)
Check_Remb.grid(column = 0, row = 4, padx = 15)
Bt_Log.place(x = 141, y = 78)

Win.mainloop()
```

Comment: When  I tried your approach of using .withdraw and .quit I cannot import the SignUp page and receive an error like this: '_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist'. I made the other window a top level and that made it work for a bit but then I couldn't return back to the login page after that occurred and I then received another error and full shutdown of the window.

Comment: Is it possible for you to get me a copy of code so that I can go through it thoroughly?

Cause for me its working like a charm.
Also I made a similar project and instead of creating new window again and again I made frames and switched between them, that is less resource taking and also efficient.
For example:
You can create 2 frames `Login_Frame` and `SignUp_Frame` and instead of `Win.destroy` you can do `Login_Frame.pack_forget()` that removes the frame from the window and u can use `Login_Frame.pack()` to recall it.